# Is there a functional difference between "2.00" and "2.00f"?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, literals, suffix

I ask because I am using the Box2D library, which calls for mostly float arguments. Although I see a lot of example code that uses the *0.00f* format, I am not quite sure if there is an actual difference between that and plain old *0.00*.

Will I be hurting myself later on by not appending the additional *f*? Is it a speed thing? Is there some sort of connotation that would need the *f* addend when others wouldn't?

**TL;DR: Why should I be using 0.00f instead of 0.00?**

Comment: Maybe you want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7662109/743214).

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391818/f-after-number-float-in-objective-c-c/2392409#2392409

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `f` suffix makes it a single precision(float) literal instead of a double precision literal. This usually means 32 bit instead of 64 bit floats.

> Floating-point constants default to type double. By using the suffixes f or l (or F or L — the suffix is not case sensitive), the constant can be specified as float or long double, respectively.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfh6f0w2(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Maybe "literal" is more appropriate than "constant". The type of the *literal* is what's in question.

Comment: `float` is not necessarily `32 bit` in size. It is implementation-defined.

Comment: Thanks, you're right "literal" seems more appropriate in this context. Fixed bit size part too.

Comment: How many bits of storage and what precision the types take is implementation dependent. 32 and 64 bits of storage is common but not universal.

Comment: So the question is: is there any "decimal" number that, through the double hop between double and float loses precision? And if there is, are the compilers really doing the conversion?

Comment: @xanatos: The typical problem is when you say `long double x = 0.1;`, instead of `0.1L`, because in that mistake you fail to take advantage of the higher precision of the long double by feeding it a less-precise type.

Comment: @xanatos: Yes, there are *many* of them.  And the compiler really has to do the conversion (either at compile time, or at runtime), because you told it to.

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference. `2.00` has type `double` and `2.00f` has type `float`. The exact precision and format implications of this depends on your platform. Whether the use of one over the other makes a practical difference in your code depends on the context in which it is used.

As an initializer for an explicity typed variable (of a fundamental numeric type), there will be no difference but when used in a function call it might potentially affect which overload or template specialization is used.

Obviously, when used as an initializer in a declaration using the `auto` *type-specifier* or as an expression in a decltype-specifier, the type of the object being declared will be affected.

```
decltype(2.00) x = 2.00f; // confusing
decltype(2.00f) y = 2.00; // also confusing

auto d = 2.00;
auto f = 2.00f;
```

Answer (score 4):

As long as you assign them to a `float`, there's absolutely no difference, since the *value* is representable precisely and correctly in all numeric types.

The important difference is the *type* of the literal, which is `double` for `2.0`, `float` for `2.0f` and `int` for `2`. So it makes a difference in argument type deduction:

```
void foo(int) { cure_cancer(); };
void foo(float) { wipe_hard_disk(); }
void foo(double) { exit(0); }

foo(2);
foo(2.0f);
foo(2.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of `2.00` is `double`, and the type of `2.00f` is `float`.

The suffix `f` turns the literal `2.00` into a float type, decreasing its precision. Otherwise, literal is `double` type.

Answer (score 2):

The default assumption is `double`.  specifying `f` suffix ensures that it will be interpreted as a `float`

Answer (score 2):

- The suffix affects the **type**, which changes *how a statement is parsed*

  This not only changes *type deduction* result via `decltype` and *function overload selection* as others said, but also **how an expression is evaluated**

  For example `2.0 * x / 3` is done in double precision, and `2.0f * x / 3` is done in float precision when x is `float`. That may lead to different results because doing in a higher precision will reduce any intermediate errors. It also affects performance greatly on FPU-less systems or systems with an FPU for `float` only, and it's a thing embedded programmers need to care about. [Demo on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:50,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:50,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:50,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:50,startLineNumber:6),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciomanip%3E%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++float+x+%3D+0.4f%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+std::setprecision(20)+%3C%3C+2.0+*+x+/+3+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%0A++++++++++++++%3C%3C+std::setprecision(20)+%3C%3C+2.0f+*+x+/+3+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:38.27563683866754,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27),(h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:61.72436316133246,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:1,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

  Here I'm assuming the [`FLT_EVAL_METHOD`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits/FLT_EVAL_METHOD) macro is set so that floating-point types are not evaluated in a higher precision. But even if `FLT_EVAL_METHOD >= 1` then the result might still be different with and without the suffix, because of the next point:
- The suffix also affects the **value**

  In C++ the value must be rounded correctly to the nearest value in the destination type. So for example when we have

  ```
  float f1 = 8388608.5000000009f;
  float f2 = 8388608.5000000009;
  ```

  then `f1` and `f2` will have different values because the suffix prevents [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) (meaning rounding twice, not the type `double`) from happening in `f2` (decimal → double → float). The decimal value is rounded to the nearest `float` value directly in `f1` (decimal → float) without going through `double`. Print the values with more precision and you'll see

  Another example:

  ```
  f1 = 7.038531e-26f;
  f2 = 7.038531e-26;
  ```

  There are many other examples that you can see in [the demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIMwDMpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQSAGykAA6oCoRODB7evnppGY4CYRHRLHEJXACstpj2RQxCBEzEBDk%2BfoG19VlNLQQlUbHxSbbNre15XGP9g2UVElUAlLaoXsTI7BzmAeHI3lgA1CYBbk4KBMSYrCfYJhoAgjt7B5jHp04shngpt/cP4QIhy%2B4QgS3%2BJgA7BZjo9DvDDlRaKgmECqFx3gARQ4ADgCOJxiQ0OIAdFUNBTKRSAJxUE5WOEIpEotFmLG4/GE4lkqlU6n0/4Iw4XdAgFBrIEnNxS4UEUUgJQEFJXZB4DICCBcDRLd7S06IjFSmVgbZVNwME2CoXWoVG/UisWK5WYVXqhia7W6mVUNl2tzHMxmExmhjB83mIMBBkPG3wq3w9HsvEEonUkmSamZrOZjSJQmQyGSMxVfGSKpmKQ4yQBSFVOlR%2BOI30BbHJrlpjPZrO5/OF4ul8uV6u1gWM%2BEO8VeSWnGUTp0qtVZD06v0Gr36y0hy1j2O2mf2uWOzBKhdu5fr/0%2Bi8BoMhsOhwOjp47xMnbGQkkafElriYAC0ZiJPW0ZCleb6HB%2BX44j%2B/6AU%2BQoTmgU7XnOx7Oq6S5aiu%2B6XoaOGHJu5rbjGu7WquqEni6i4alh15gfhEb3kxj4No8javi2hxaryXDpl22bwUyzbYtxVK8Z2/G0oJ46HpO056v6FHodR7q0auHEKQRppEdsO6kShsnzlRZ5qfh9GaYxd53ix0aNuxeEibyFI8k5GhcNJTbsqJVIuU5XDAY2iESgZ8pGRhNGeupeGaYRFq6SR%2BlxvhSmnphkVmc2FmPlZ4Y2XZL4OYcGiqBoJIAGIVZVkKVZVbgpBoHn0dixWlTVFXVW1dUaAFO5Bch5GGWhqURdhmkaca2lxY2%2BkDaFQ3GWlo3eplMqWeG1mRrZkKYv8HArLQnBVLwfgcFopCoJw0qWNYwprBsbw7DwpAEJoe0rAA1iA%2BIkmYtaJAEeb4okiS1tIB0cJIvAsBIFKkCdZ0XRwvAKCAGjPa9KxwLASBoCwKR0PE5CULj%2BP0AkwBcFwZh8HQBDxCjEAxK9pAxOELQAJ6cE9uNsIIADyDC0Jzp28FgXxGOIIukPgKqOAAbpgKNS5gqgulOWxnYCdTM7QeAxMQHMeFgzOXHg0PcHtfAGMACgAGp4JgADufMpIwXO8PwggiGI7BSDIgiKCo6hS7o0wGEYKDWNY%2Bh6yjkArKgKQNErf58wEyN1C6DQuAw7ieB0eihOEQzlCM0wFJkAiTH45fpJXDBzMMlTdFnvTjG0%2BdTC3Dht7MxfzGXMwTJ3NdDwM/dNxIKwKHdmx6JcmBbDw%2B2HcdzOI6ohJ/okkiHMAyDIFxvFshAV1WJYpCHLghAkAGATTIcHh4wTxB31wSy8C9IuY0gEopFORMIAkxfpEVgWxN6JG3rvfeh9KY/V4JgfARBiB4FFNMT2whRDiD9hgwOahmah1II7A2KR3Yrw4EdOG69OB8ynP/IEqAqCHAgVAveB8j4/UOKfVAz8yZvw/ujb%2BKwEDXCwAkMEpBPqJF4pCMw1Z/pcGkQEAIcjkjg0hlQqWiNkbzwxuQswa8tGcE/no0gCtiBuhAJIIAA)

### See also

- [When does appending an 'f' change the value of a floating constant when assigned to a `float`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66631288/995714)
- [The type of a floating point literal with exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62599516/995714)
- [Notation of double floating point values in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13279512/995714)
- [What's the use of suffix `f` on float value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17505011/995714)
- [Is there any difference between using floating point casts vs floating point suffixes in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65142902/995714)
- [What is the difference between casting to `float` and adding `f` as a suffix when initializing a `float`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33163772/995714)
- ["i < 0.7" is true following an "float i = 0.7" initialization above?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13590519/995714)

Comment: Nice summary...

Comment: Nice summary, indeed. This 'double rounding' can affect compile time slightly. Can't it?