# "i < 0.7" is true following an "float i = 0.7" initialization above?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Floating point comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011184/floating-point-comparison)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
float i=0.7;
clrscr();
if(i < 0.7)
     printf("If Block");
else
     printf("Else Block");
getch();
return 0;
}
```

I dont understand whay the output will be "If block".....please help why the if part is executed?

Comment: Use either `double` or `0.7f`.

Comment: Spend an hour or so and read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). It will be a real eye-opener if you're fuzzy on floating point approximation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually `i` is `0.69999999998` in it's floating representation.

When you assign `i=0.7` in memory 0.7 cannot be represented in `double precision` as you would have thought.

So the comparison between `float` and `double` leads to type promotion and in that case `i` is less than `0.7` which is double.

Comment: shouldn't 0.7 always round to the same value, causing the comparison to consistently fail?

Comment: @JanDvorak: no, the comparison is between a `float` and a `double`, so the `float` is promoted and compared as `double`.

Comment: 0.7 is by default double

Comment: The key ingredient is the implicit double=>float cast that rounds down, then compares to the original double.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: If the original code used `0.7f` instead of just `0.7`, the comparison would fail, since if would indeed be represented identically. But `0.7` by itself is a `double`, which is represented differently than that `float i`.

Comment: `(double)((float)0.7) != 0.7` -- there's loss of precision in the conversions.