# What is the difference between casting to `float` and adding `f` as a suffix when initializing a `float`?

Tags: c, casting, floating-point

What is the difference between

```
float f = (float) 99.32 ;
```

and

```
float f = 99.32f ;
```

Both of them compiled and ran successfully.

Comment: The first suffers from [double rounding error](http://www.exploringbinary.com/double-rounding-errors-in-floating-point-conversions/), which is not good as the result might not be the desired value. The second one produces a correctly rounded float value https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding

Comment: That link uses way too long a representation of its example number. "0.50000008940696713" is sufficient.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: I expect it used a precise decimal representation of a value halfway between two adjacent double values, though I would suggest that adding a large integer to the value would make precise decimal representations much shorter and more obvious.

Comment: 1. Do you mean, for that decimal string specifically, or for any one? 2. What does "successfully" mean? "Returned the same value"? (Do they test as equal? Did you examine the *entire* representation?)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
float f = 99.32f ;
```

That is a `float` literal, which means a float variable being assigned with a `float` value directly.

```
float f = (float) 99.32 ;
```

That is a  `float` variable that is assigned a `double` value that is cast to `float` before being assigned.

Comment: Would the compiler optimize this out? (in the cast case)

Comment: @Austi01101110 Depends on the compiler, and what you later do with it. Not in all compilers is that equivalent in assembly code. If you use the second option you get 2x rounding, once when casting to a double, another time when casting to float.

Comment: Where is a cast to `double`?

Comment: `99.32` without f is an implied cast to a double.

Comment: no, `99.32` is a floating point literal, which has the type `double`.

Comment: So you are casting the value `99.32` to a `double` by declaring it a floating point literal of default type `double`. In this case the decimal representation is rounded to a `double`, and then again to a float by the explicit cast, whilst in the first example float `f = 99.32f ;` the decimal value is beeing directly cast to a `float`

Comment: no, `99.32` is a `double`, not implicit casted to it. This is called  "floating point literal of type `double`". `99.32f` is a `float` and not casted to it. This is called "floating point literal of type `float`". There is no cast at `float f = 99.32f;` or `double d = 99.32;`.

Comment: Maybe im using the word "cast" wrong. I mean that by the second method, you are assigning the decimal value `99.32` as a double, subjecting it to the initial rounding for a double. When you then cast to a `float`, you subject it again to the initial rounding of a float.

Comment: @Magisch: That's correct. Earlier you were suggesting that simply writing a literal involves a cast, which is incorrect.

Comment: @mch The only point here is that `99.32` is a representation of a number in decimal notation and whatever technically correct word you prefer use for converting/casting/whatever it by the compiler into a `double` (normally a binary notation internally), that operation might lose precision.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev That's true, but that's not complete. The five-character `99.32` literal is by default converted by a compiler to a `double` type representation; this is one convertion. Then explicit `(float)` cast causes another convertion from `double` type to `float`. And the final result *may* differ from a one-step conversion from a 6-characters literal `99.32f` to a `float` type representation.

Comment: Is there any difference in value between the two?

Comment: @Austi01101110 The compiler might optimize out the cost of doing a runtime conversion, but that doesn't mean it would give the same value.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Rare, and likely not in this case. (float) 99.32 is the real number 99.32, rounded to the nearest available double number, rounded to the nearest available float number. 99.32f is the real number 99.32, rounded to the nearest float number. Let x be a number that is exactly halfway between two neighbouring float numbers. Let d and d' be two decimal numbers that is just a tiny tiny bit larger/smaller than x. Then the .f suffix would be rounded up/down, but rounding to double might give the result x in both cases, and casting to float will round either d or d' in the wrong direction.

Comment: @gnasher729 An excellent observation. I think you should make it into an answer, perhaps. Maybe when I have time I will try to find a "nice" (i.e. not too many decimal digits in the source code literal) example where rounding to nearest `double` followed by rounding to nearest `float` gives something different from doing just one round to `float`.

Comment: @gnasher729  Can You Tell Me Difference Between float f = 99.32 and float f = (float)99.32

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Deleted

Comment: @SurajJain: You deleted your comments then just repeated your original comment, now to somebody else. _If you have a new question, post a new question._ I don't know how to be any clearer about this, Suraj.

Comment: @SurajJain This has been answered here a dozen times or more already. Simply put, `f = 99,32` is an implicit cast and `float f = (float) 99.32` is an explicit cast. Search for what both mean on google.

Comment: @Magisch Does It Makes Any Difference, That is why i am asking.

Comment: @SurajJain It depends. Depends on your compiler, depends on your optimization level, depends on the precision you need, on your specific use case. I can't give you a definitive answer on that.

Comment: @Magisch Can We Have Chat?

Answer (score 25):

The difference may be optimized away, but in the first case you have a double literal that is type casted to a float while you have a float literal in the second case.

If not optimized away you will get a typecast in the code in the second example.

However there are corner cases where the result could (depending on rounding mode) be slightly different. If your number can't be exactly represented you will in the first case get rounding twice - first when you round the decimal representation to a double and then when you round that to a float, while in the first case you round the decimal representation directly to a float.

Comment: Since an ULP in single-precision is so much larger than an ULP in double precision, I find it hard to believe the doubled rounding could have a significant effect.

Comment: "However there are corner cases where the result could (depending on rounding mode) be slightly different." - examples?

Comment: @Kevin It would have an effect of up to one _float_ ULP difference.

Comment: I suspect a corner case does exist, but have not found it.

Comment: 0.50000008940696713 yields a different result: with rounding you get `0x1.000004p-1` while with suffix you get `0x1.000002p-1` (see http://ideone.com/EV3QeG). See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding

Comment: More specifically, last two digits of 11-21 all result in `0x1.000003p-1` as double (and therefore `0x1.000004p-1` when double-rounded to float), and last two digits of 11-16 (roughly half of this range) result in `0x1.000002p-1`. So the range of values over which this can occur (for each instance, presumably spaced one float ULP apart) is roughly one half of one double ULP wide, and in every case yields an "error" of one half of one float ULP when rounded up or down, since the real values are roughly halfway between two float values.

Comment: @JanDvorak: It can mean the difference between a float which is about .500000001 way from the specified value and one which is .499999999 away.  In most cases where it would matter which result is chosen, one should use a double representation that's not almost half an ulp away from the desired float.

Answer (score 11):

In the first case without the cast `99.32` is interpreted as double not as a float.

A double literal is being casted to float.

In the second case you have a suffix `f` to make sure the compiler treats `99.32` as float.

Answer (score 11):

In the line `float f = (float) 99.32;` the literal `99.32` is created as a `double` type by default and is then cast to a `float`.

In the line `float f = 99.32f ;` the literal is created as a `float` type due to the trailing `f` in `99.32f` and no type casting is required.

The latter would be analogous to writing `double f = 99.32;` as you'd have a `double` type being assigned directly to a variable of a matching type.

Answer (score 10):

Floating point literals without a suffix are by default of `double` type.

Thus, stating `float f = (float) 99.32;` you first cast **explicitly** literal `99.32` which is of type `double` to a `float` and then assign it to variable `f`.

Stating `float f = 99.32;` does the same thing but in this case the **conversion between types is done implicitly.**

If you want to avoid implicit conversion you should use the `f` suffix to define your literal (i.e., `float f = 99.32f;`)

Comment: no they're not the same thing, [without the `f` suffix the result is sometimes wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68586856/995714)

Answer (score 6):

The difference is that the literal `99.32` is of type double, while the literal `99.32f` is of type float.

The first statement assigns the float literal to a float variable. Nothing special.

The second statement casts a double literal to a float, and assigns the result to a float variable.

As far as the standard is concerned, you can assign a double literal to a float variable, without explicitly casting it yourself. In that case implicit cast occurs. E.g. :

```
float f = 99.32;
```

You can even do :

```
float f = (double) 10.5f;
```

and the right hand side is still implicitly converted to a float.

Please note that most modern compilers optimize those away, so representing floats is usually matter of style and preference. **Just be consistent.**

Comment: This's wrong, **they're not purely for consistency** but they're required for accuracy. [Without the `f` suffix the result is sometimes wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68586856/995714). Always use `f` for `float` and `L` for `long double`