# The type of a floating point literal with exponent

Tags: c, floating-point

What is the type of a floating-point literal having an exponent part, such as the `123456e-3` in C(99+)? Is it of type `float` or `double`? When used as a `float` initializer in `float f = 123456e-3;`
does it need to have a `f` suffix?

Comment: It is `double`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant

Comment: The floating-point literal has type `double` unless it has a suffix. The value of the initializer will be converted to `float` in the same way as for a simple assignment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, all floating point literals, with or without an exponent part, have type `double`.  You can add the `f` suffix to make the type `float` or `L` to make the type `long double`.

In the case of `float f = 123456e-3;`, you're initializing a `float` with a `double` constant, so there is the possibility of loss of precision, however this particular constant only has 6 decimal digits of precision so it should be OK.

Comment: Here, both `float f = 123456e-3;` and `float f = 123456e-3f;` result in `0x1.edd2f2p+6` being stored. However it is a best practice to initialize `float` variables with `float` literal constants, to avoid potential issues with double rounding.

Answer (score 7):

For floating point literal, if no suffix is defined, it will be automatically considered as `double`.

You can follow this chart for suffix:

```
(no suffix) - double

f/F - float

l/L - long double
```

So, for float, it needs to have `f` or `F` suffix.

Answer (score 7):

> What is the type of a floating-point literal?

**Floating constants**

C defines these as *floating constants*, not *literals*.  Default type is `double`.
An `f` or `F` suffix makes it a `float`.
An `l` or `L` suffix makes it a `long double`.

**[edit] `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`**

C has `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` which allows *constants* to be *interpreted* as a wider type.

Example `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2`

> evaluate all operations and constants to the range and precision of the `long double` type.

In this case, I'd expect `v1` and `v2` to have the same value when `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2`, but different values when `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 0`.

```
long double v1 = 0.1;
long double v2 = 0.1L;
```

---

> When used as a float initializer in float f = 123456e-3; does it need to have a f suffix?

For best conversion of the text to `float`, yes use an `f`.

`float f = 123456e-3` incurs [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding).  2 rounding occurs: text->`double` and `double` to `float`.

With select values, `g` may get a different value with `float g = x.xxx` vs `g = x.xxxf;`.  See following.

**[double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) example**

Notice `f2` and `f4` have the same constant except the the `f` suffix.  Compiler warns with `f4`:

> warning: conversion from 'double' to 'float' changes value from '9.9999997019767761e-1' to '1.0e+0f' [-Wfloat-conversion]

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
  // float has 24 bit significand, double has 53
  float f1 = 0x0.FFFFFFp0f;         // code with 24 bit significand, exact as a float
  printf("%-20a %.17e\n", f1, f1);
  float f2 = 0x0.FFFFFF7FFFFFFCp0f; // code with 54 bit significand, rounds down to nearest float
  printf("%-20a %.17e\n", f2, f2);
  float f3 = 0x0.FFFFFF80000000p0f; // code with 25 bit significand, rounds up to nearest float
  printf("%-20a %.17e\n", f3, f3);
  puts("");
  double d1 = 0x0.FFFFFF7FFFFFF8p0; // code constant with 53 bit significand, exact as a double
  printf("%-20a %.17e\n", d1, d1);
  double d2 = 0x0.FFFFFF7FFFFFFCp0; // code constant with 54 bit significand, rounds up to nearest double
  printf("%-20a %.17e\n", d2, d2);
  float f4 = 0x0.FFFFFF7FFFFFFCp0;  // code constant with 54 bit significand, rounds up to nearest double
                                    // then rounds up again when double converted to float
  printf("%-20a %.17e\n", f4, f4);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0x1.fffffep-1        9.99999940395355225e-01
0x1.fffffep-1        9.99999940395355225e-01  f2
0x1p+0               1.00000000000000000e+00

0x1.fffffefffffffp-1 9.99999970197677501e-01
0x1.ffffffp-1        9.99999970197677612e-01
0x1p+0               1.00000000000000000e+00  f4 Double Rounding!
```

---

For best conversion of the text to `long double`, definitely use an `L` else the constant is only a `double` with less precision.

```
long double ld1 = 0x1.00000000000001p1;
printf("%.20Le\n", ld1, ld1);
long double ld2 = 0x1.00000000000001p1L; // "Same" constant as above with an 'L'
printf("%.20Le\n", ld2, ld2);
```

Output

```
2.00000000000000000000e+00
2.00000000000000002776e+00
```