# Why does float have different decimals than double?

Tags: c, floating-point

For example if `double a = 34.837864` and `float b = (float)a` why does `b` have different decimals if `b` is in the range of float?

Or in this other example:

```
float a = 3.38776326737464747726337264343434334434343;
double b = 3.38776326737464747726337264343434334434343; 

printf("%.16f\n%.16lf",a,b);
```

The output is `a=3.3877632617950439` and `b=3.3877632673746474`. We can see that there are some decimals that are different.

Why does the output has different decimals if both of them are printing the same number and this number is in the range of float and double?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: `double` doesn't merely have a greater *range* than `float`, it also has greater *precision* (more significant figures).

Comment: Internally, both `float` and `double` use *binary* floating point.  Type `float` has 24 bits worth of precision, and `double` has 53 bits.  Your number 3.38776326737... is (in binary) `0b11.0110001101000100011101` as a `float`, and `0b11.011000110100010001110100000101111111011011010110110` as a `double`.  You can see that, in binary, the `float` representation is a subset of `double`.  But when you convert back to decimal, you get (approximately) 3.3877632618 and 3.38776326737464739, which don't quite match so well — although they do have the prefix 3.38776326 in common.

Comment: [Is there a functional difference between "2.00" and "2.00f"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7697148/995714)