# Suffixes for numerical constants in C: when should they be used?

Tags: c, literals

I've used C for scientific programming for more than 15 years and I've never needed  suffixes like `F` and `L` for numerical literals. I wonder why some very experienced programmers almost always use them. Here are two examples:

```
float x = 1.5F;
unsigned short *biosPtr = (unsigned short *)0x400000L;
```

Obviously, there are other cases where the suffixes are important. For example

```
(-1 < 100)
```

is `true`, but

```
(-1 < 100U)
```

is `false`.

Comment: In the first case, if you put `float x = 1.5;` the compiler complains about truncation of `double` to `float`.

Comment: @WeatherVane, GCC doesn't do that, even with `-Wall` flag.

Comment: [what is the reason for explicitly declaring L or UL for long values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13134956/995714), [Is there a functional difference between "2.00" and "2.00f"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7697148/995714), [When does appending an 'f' change the value of a floating constant when assigned to a `float`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66631288/995714)

Comment: The `1.5` is exactly representable as both `float` and `double`. What does gcc say about `float x = 1.4;`?

Comment: @phuclv, thanks. I need one hour for reading them. :)

Comment: @WeatherVane, It behaves the same.

Comment: in C++ you'll need them even more due to the use of templates. @apadana simple statements like `float x = 1.4;` might work the same but not others